# Tell the difference between a recorded and selected video

Tags: ios, objective-c, video

I am working on adding video to a chat application. The users can either share a video chosen from their files or record a new one to upload.

The issue I am having is differentiating between a video which has just been recorded and a video which has been selected as I want to save a just recorded video to their album when they upload it.

Currently my code looks like this:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    // This checks whether we are adding image or video (public.movie for video)
    if ([[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType] isEqualToString:@"public.image"]) {

        UIImage * image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];

        [self sendImage:image];
    }
    else {

        // SS-V
        // If we are dealing with a video then we want to return to the chat view and post the video
        NSURL * videoURL = (NSURL *)[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];

        // Send video to the chat view
        [self sendVideo:[videoURL absoluteString]];
    }

    [tableView reloadData];
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];
}
```

So I am getting the local url of the video and then uploading it to an external database.

I have also got this code:

```
// Save the recorded video to the iPhone
NSString * videoCompatibleString = [videoURL.absoluteString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"file://" withString:@""];

if (UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum(videoCompatibleString)) {

    UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum (videoCompatibleString, self, nil, nil);
}
```

Which will save it to my phone library.

So now my only issue is how to differentiate between a video just taken and a video selected from my library already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was hoping there would be an elegant way of achieving this. Seemingly there isn't and so I set up an enum to record what I loaded the image picker with, if I loaded it with the camera then I knew that I would be taking the video or picture so should add it to the album:

In the header file:

```
typedef enum {
    bPictureTypeCamera,
    bPictureTypeAlbumImage,
    bPictureTypeAlbumVideo,
} bPictureType;

// This allows us to see what kind of media is being sent to know if we need to save it to album
bPictureType _pictureType;
```

In the main file:

```
// If we have just taken the media then save it to the users camera
if (_pictureType == bPictureTypeCamera) {
    [self saveMediaWithInfo:info];
}
```

With my save function checking if it is video or image and saving it:

```
- (void)saveMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary *)info {

    // Save image
    if ([[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType] isEqualToString:@"public.image"]) {

        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum([info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage], self, nil, nil);
    }
    // Save Video
    else {

        // Make sure the video is in a compatible format to save
        NSURL * videoURL = (NSURL *)[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
        NSString * videoCompatibleString = [[videoURL absoluteString] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"file://" withString:@""];

        if (UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum (videoCompatibleString)) {

            UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum (videoCompatibleString, self, nil, nil);
        }
    }
}
```

Now the neatest answer but it does what it needs to